# Module outside application folder in zend

Tags: zend-framework

I have directory structure like this

```
Application
    Config
        application.ini
    Controllers
    modules
        default
        admin
    Bootstrap.php
Install
    Controllers
    views
    Bootstrap.php
index.php
```

I want Install/Bootstrap.php to run first.
How and where to define such configuration?
How to define route for Install module?

Answer (score 0):

I created an installer for one of my reusable ZF sites. I think you are going about it wrong.

This is how I accomplished it:

1. I actually have 2 different Zend applications. One is strictly for installation, one is my application that needs one time setup.
2. They both share one library directory
3. the .htaccess in the webroot by default points the user to install.php (which calls up the bootstrap for the installation application.
4. the last step of the installation application is to modify the .htaccess to send all future requests to index.php (the actual application), and deny access to all for the install.php file

My Directory Structure

```
|-application
|  |-modules
|  |  |-default
|  |  |-admin
|  |-config
|  |-Bootstrap.php
|-public (webroot)
|  |-index.php
|  |-install.php
|  |-.htaccess
|-private
|  |-installer
|  |  |-application
|  |  |  |-modules
|  |  |  |  |-default
|  |  |  |-config
|  |  |  |-Bootstrap.php
|-library
|  |-Zend
```